# using underscore templates with Backbone and Require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm trying to create a simple app using underscore templates and backbone (as described in [this article](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/)). I'm sure that the template file is being loaded correctly, but I'm not so sure whether I'm applying the model to the template properly. (See below example)

I have also checked the output of `compiledTemplate` variable, but it only contains the  `<h1> </h1>` tags, so it looks like there may be something wrong with the format of my model. But I have not been able to come up witjh any solution so far  hence I'm posting this here hoping that someone could possibly help me out with this ..

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="./dev_env/app/libs/vendor/require.min.js" data-main="dev_env/app/main"></script>
    <script>
        require(['app_init']);
    </script>
</head>
<body >

        <div id="test">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**./templates/template.html**

```
<h1> <%= obj.title  %> </h1>
```

**./app_init.js**

```
require([ '../app' ], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

**./app.js**

```
define([ 'backbone', './router', 'underscore','jquery'], function (Backbone, Router, _,  $) {
          var initialize = function(){
            Router.initialize();
          }

          return {
            initialize: initialize
          };
    });
```

**./models/model_menu.js**

```
define([ 'underscore',  'backbone' ], function(_, Backbone){
  var MenuModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: "Test1"
    }
  });

  return MenuModel;
});
```

**./collections/collection_menu.js**

```
define([ 'underscore',  'backbone',  'models/model_menu'
], function(_, Backbone, MenuModel){
  var MenuCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MenuModel
  });

  return MenuCollection;
});
```

**./router.js**

```
define(['jquery','underscore', 'backbone', 'views/menu/view_menu'],  function ($, _, Backbone, vMenu) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes : {
                'menu' : 'showMenu',

            }
        });

    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('route:showMenu', function () {
            var MyMenu = new vMenu();
            MyMenu.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };
});
```

**./views/menu_view/view_menu.js**

```
define([ 'jquery','underscore', 'backbone', 'collections/collection_menu', 'text!templates/template.html' ], function ($, _, Backbone, MenuCollection,  myTempl) {
    var MenuViiew = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#test'),
        initialize : function () {
            this.collection = new MenuCollection();
            this.collection.add( {title: "Title2"});

            var compiledTemplate = _.template( myTempl, { obj : this.collection.models} );
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
        }
    });

    return MenuViiew;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I now understand where I was wrong, I misunderstand what a collection was therefore I couldn't make it work. Apologies for that, but I'm still learning this stuff.

here's the solution:

*btw. I have changed the  **collection_menu** to **menu_collections** so it's clear that the file contains a collection of menu models.*

**views/view_model.js**

```
define([ 'jquery','underscore', 'backbone', 'collections/menu_collections', 'text!templates/template.html' ], function ($, _, Backbone, MenuCollections, myTempl) {
    var MenuViiew = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#alex'),

        initialize : function () {
            this.collection = new MenusCollection()
            this.collection.add({ title: "Test1" });
            this.collection.add({ title: "Test2" });
        },
        render: function(){
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(myTempl, { menus : this.collection.models});
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
        }
    });

    return MenuViiew;
});
```

**./templates/template.html**

```
<% _.each(menus, function(menu) { %>
    <h1> <%= menu.get('title')  %> </h1>
<% }); %>
```